# How can I encapsulate the jQuery get method so I can call it as another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to encapsulate the jQuery `get` method in a function.

How do I do that properly?

The following just returns a get object when I call `getMyData()`:

```
function getMyData() {
    return $.get("www.mysite.com/data", function(data) {
               return data;
           });
}
```

I want to be able to call `getMyData()` to return the data object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of jQuery's various AJAX methods (such as `$.get`, `$.getJSON` and `$.ajax`) are asynchronous (That's the 'A' in AJAX).

They return a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) object which can be used to ascertain when the data has been received. Therefore you could do this:

```
function getMyData() {
    return $.get("www.mysite.com/data")
}
```

and call it like so:

```
getMyData().done(function(data){
     // here data is received
});
```

Another option is to pass your method a callback function to be called once the data is received

```
function getMyData(callback) {
    $.get({
         url:"www.mysite.com/data",
         success: callback
    })
}
```

And call it like this:

```
function myCallback(data){
    // here data is received
}
getMyData(myCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I'm guessing the answer is simply no? You just can't encapsulate it so you'd just have to call `getMyData()` to get the data object it seems.

Comment: Of course you can encapsulate it, but as ajax is asynchronous you wont (short of breaking it by forcing it to be synchronous) get the response straight away

Answer (score -3):

Instead of `get` use jquery `ajax` and send your requet with `async`= `false`

```
function getMyData()
{
     var result = null;
     $.ajax({
        url: "www.mysite.com/data",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        } 
     });
     return result;
}
```

Comment: -1: Don't suggest breaking ajax by setting it to sync.